# How do I install the YM4R/GM plugin in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-plugins

How do I install the YM4R/GM plugin in rails 4.0.2?

I am trying to render a map in my page.
I tried installing the plugin using:

```
rails plugin new rubyforge.org/var/svn/ym4r/Plugins/GM/trunk/ym4r_gm
```

But looks like this didn't work.

As suggested in http://www.developer.com/open/article.php/3757576/Adding-Google-Maps-To-Your-Rails-Applications.htm
I added the following code to my controller:

```
class MapController < ApplicationController
  def home
   # Create a new map object, also defining the div ("map") 
   # where the map will be rendered in the view
   @map = GMap.new("map")
   # Use the larger pan/zoom control but disable the map type
   # selector
   @map.control_init(:large_map => true,:map_type => false)
   # Center the map on specific coordinates and focus in fairly
   # closely
   @map.center_zoom_init([41.023849,-80.682053], 10)
  end
end
```

And added this code to my view:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Test</title>
      <%= GMap.header %>
      <%= @map.to_html %>
   </head>
   <body>
    <h1>My First map</h1>
    <%= @map.div(:width => 400, :height => 300) %>
   </body>
</html>
```

But I am getting this error in the web page:

```
uninitialized constant MapController::GMap
```

My best guess is that the plugin was not installed correctly, I am fairly new to rails, and it's the best time I've tried to install a plugin, so I probably did it wrong. Does anybody know what the problem is here? I'm using Rails 4.0.2 and ruby 1.9.3p484 on a Windows 8 computer.

Comment: I thought Rails was moving away from plug-ins to gems only ? Pierre

Comment: @user1854802 ooh, I didn't know that, as I mentioned I am very new to Rails, but if that's true it would make sense I cannot install the plugin.

Comment: Apologies about vague answer.  This link may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025566/how-do-i-install-the-ym4r-gm-plugin-in-rails-4?noredirect=1#comment37066615_24025566 - Pierre

Comment: @user1854802 I think you added the wrong link, this link redirects me to my own question :P